# Closing a JFrame with the dispose-function with actionlistener

Tags: java, swing

I want to close a JFrame with a button.
The frame.dispose() method works on other methods but it doesn't on the ActionListener of the JButton.

The issue is located in the class FileChooser in the annoynmous class "ActionListener" of the JButton  (okButton).
In general my goal is to close the second (the first window is the one created on main.class) window with clicking the Jbutton(OKButton).

```
package gui;

import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FileChooser extends JPanel
                             implements ActionListener {
    static private final String newline = "\n";
    JButton openButton, saveButton, okButton;
    JTextArea log;
    JFileChooser fc;
    String absolutePaths;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Management");


    public FileChooser() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        //Create the log first, because the action listeners
        //need to refer to it.
        
        log = new JTextArea(5,20);
        log.setMargin(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
        log.setEditable(false);
        
        JScrollPane logScrollPane = new JScrollPane(log);

        //Create a file chooser
        fc = new JFileChooser();
 


        //Create the open button.  We use the image from the JLF
        //Graphics Repository (but we extracted it from the jar).
        openButton = new JButton("Open a File...",
                                 createImageIcon("images/Open16.gif"));
        openButton.addActionListener(this);

        //Create the save button.  We use the image from the JLF
        //Graphics Repository (but we extracted it from the jar).
        saveButton = new JButton("Save a File...",
                                 createImageIcon("images/Save16.gif"));
        saveButton.addActionListener(this);
        
        okButton = new JButton("OK");
                
        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
             System.out.println("test");
             main.frame.setPathsTextField("Pfad:     " + getAbsolutePaths());
           // ***THIS IS THE PROBLEM WHICH DOESNT WORK***
             frame.dispose();
             
             
            }
        });
        
        //For layout purposes, put the buttons in a separate panel
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(); //use FlowLayout
        JPanel buttonBot = new JPanel(); //use FlowLayout
        buttonPanel.add(openButton);
        buttonBot.add(okButton);
       

        //Add the buttons and the log to this panel.
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(logScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttonBot, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //Handle open button action.
        if (e.getSource() == openButton) {
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileChooser.this);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                //This is where a real application would open the file.
                log.append("Opening: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
                log.append(file.getAbsolutePath());
                setAbsolutePaths(file.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                log.append("Open command cancelled by user." + newline);
            }
            log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());

        //Handle save button action.
        } else if (e.getSource() == saveButton) {
            int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(FileChooser.this);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                //This is where a real application would save the file.
                log.append("Saving: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
                setAbsolutePaths(file.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                log.append("Save command cancelled by user." + newline);
            }
            log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());
        }
    }

    /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = FileChooser.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
    
   
    
    

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
       
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add content to the window.
        frame.add(new FileChooser());
        frame.setResizable(false);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
      
    }

    public String getAbsolutePaths() {
        return absolutePaths;
    }
    public void setAbsolutePaths(String absolutePaths) {
        this.absolutePaths = absolutePaths;
    }
    public void diposeWindow() {
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.dispose();
    }
  

}
```

In order you want to compile (probably thats an easy thing, but maybe it helps for someone)
here is the sourcecode of the class which needs to compile.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.Scrollbar;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JMenu;
import java.awt.Button;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.TextField;

public class main extends JFrame {
    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    TextField textFieldPaths = new TextField();
    static main frame = new main();

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    
                    

                    frame.setTitle("Just The Name");
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public main() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        setResizable(false);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        
        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setBounds(41, 216, 329, 14);
        contentPane.add(progressBar);
        
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Janitza", "Not implemented yet.", "Not implemented yet.", "---"}));
        comboBox.setToolTipText("");
        comboBox.setBounds(41, 11, 153, 20);
        contentPane.add(comboBox);
        

        
        textFieldPaths.setBounds(41, 181, 329, 22);
        textFieldPaths.setEditable(false);
        textFieldPaths.setText("Pfad:    ");
        contentPane.add(textFieldPaths);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Datei...");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(42, 136, 89, 23);
        
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fc.createAndShowGUI();

            }
        });
        
        
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    public void setPathsTextField(String text) {
        textFieldPaths.setText(text);
        
    }
    
    public String getPathsTextField() {
        return textFieldPaths.getText();
    
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: do you want to close your complete program or just the JFrame?

Comment: I want to close the 2nd Window (so just the JFrame).
I basically want the same functionality of what the press of the "X" would do. But to have it as intuitive as possible I want to have it included in the OK button.

Comment: Does the button work?

Comment: What do you mean by that?
Yes, the button works. The Sysout statement e.g works. But the method-call doesnt.

Comment: Will the "test" be printed for you?

Comment: Yes the test prints.

Comment: Try if "frame.getWidth ()" is printed

Comment: (To test if the frame is correct)

Comment: In this case It prints "0".

Comment: then it could be that it is the wrong window, because your window is definitely not 0px wide or long

Comment: do you want to close the window of the jfilechooser?

Comment: Yes, I just want the have the main window left opened.

Comment: ok wait 1min ill search for an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your class design.

In your main() class you have:

```
FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
```

And in the `createAndShowGUI()` methdo you have:

```
frame.add(new FileChooser());
```

so you have two instance of the `FileChooser` class lying around.

The code in the createAndShowGUI() method should be moved to the ActionListener of your main() class.

Your `FileChooser` class does not need a reference to the "JFrame". It is just a component that can be added to a frame or a dialog etc.

Then in the ActionListener of the "Ok" button you do:

```
JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(button);
window.dispose();
```